# Key Binding for Music and Fn Keys

Tags: mouse, shortcut-keys

I've been trying to figure out the key bindings for xbindkeys and it hasn't been working very well.

I'm trying to bind the 8, 9, 10, and 13 keys of my Logitech Performance MX mouse (those are the keys to the side) for music functions. I've retrieved the mouse buttons and keystrokes using

```
xbindkeys -k
kev
```

So far, this is what I've come up with to put in the gedit $HOME/.xbindkeysrc file

```
"xte 'keys m0x0 + c:171"
b: 8

"xte 'keys m0x0 + c:173'"
b: 9    

"xte 'keys m0x0 + c:172'"
b: 10

"xte 'keys m0x0 + c:121'"
b: 13
```

Similarly I've also tried the configurations below, with no success:

```
"xte 'keys XF86AudioNext'"
b: 8

"xte 'keys XF86AudioPrev'"
b: 9    

"xte 'keys XF86AudioPlay'"
b: 10

"xte 'keys XF86AudioMute'"
b: 13
```

If someone can help, that'll be great thanks!